# Selenium ElementNotInteractableException on logining twitter

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a problem with login to twitter. I searched on google but I couldn't find my answer so I am asking to you. Here is my code

```
driver.get("https://twitter.com/login");
Thread.sleep(2000);
driver.findElement(By.name("session[username_or_email]")).click();
Thread.sleep(1000);
driver.findElement(By.name("session[username_or_email]")).sendKeys("**removed***");
Thread.sleep(1000);
driver.findElement(By.name("session[password]")).click();
Thread.sleep(1000);
driver.findElement(By.name("session[password]")).sendKeys("**removed***");
```

Comment: findElement(By.name("session[username_or_email]")) it's giving multiple list of webelment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it has 3 elements with same name, use `driver.findElements` with `s` and select second element.

```
driver.findElements(By.name("session[username_or_email]")).get(1).click();
Thread.sleep(1000);
driver.findElements(By.name("session[username_or_email]")).get(1).sendKeys("**removed***");
Thread.sleep(1000);
driver.findElements(By.name("session[password]")).get(1).click();
Thread.sleep(1000);
driver.findElements(By.name("session[password]")).get(1).sendKeys("**removed***");
```

Comment: Now I have a problem with submitting the form here is my code https://github.com/bbaransahin/Twitter-Bot/blob/master/Start.java can you help pls?

Comment: cannot click submit button? try third index `driver.findElements(By.tagName("form")).get(2).submit();` or your previous code `driver.findElement(By.className("submit EdgeButton EdgeButton--primary EdgeButtom--medium")).click();`

Comment: Ok my previous code couldn't find the button but I'll try third index ty

Comment: And can you explain how you decide to use third one ?